# Calling a Web API action that has same signature as another

Tags: controller, asp.net-core-mvc, action, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

I have an ASP .Net Core 1.1 Web Api. In one of my controllers, I'd like two actions:

```
[HttpGet("{userId:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromRoute] int id)
{
    return Ok(_context.User.Where(u.Id == id));
}

[HttpGet("{groupId:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersInGroup([FromRoute] int groupId)
{
    return Ok(_context.User.Where(u.GroupId == groupId));
}
```

Both actions have the same signature, except for the method name. How can I make it so that I can call upon the one or the other?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it from the routing component's point of view. What would you do if you receive a URL like `/api/users/123` and you have the above actions in a controller?

You have to differentiate them, with e.g. attributes:

```
[Route("api/users")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{userId:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromRoute] int userId)
    {
        return Ok(_context.User.Where(u.Id == userId));
    }

    [HttpGet("group/{groupId:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersInGroup([FromRoute] int groupId)
    {
        return Ok(_context.User.Where(u.GroupId == groupId));
    }
}
```

Now they can be accessed with:

- `/api/users/123`
- `/api/users/group/123`

The controller-level Route-attribute sets a common prefix for all routes so you don't need to specify it for all of them.

Then the HttpGet attribute specifies an additional prefix so they are fundamentally different routes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would using a query string be possible? And if so, would it be considered "unRestful"? For example, "/api/users/123" to get a specific user, and "/api/users?groupId=5" to get all users in a group...

Comment: That would also be possible. You can use the FromQuery attribute IIRC to get query values. I don't think it is blatantly unRESTful since you are looking up users but have a search parameter. Another option could be to have the routes as `/api/users/123` and `/api/groups/123/members`. Use whatever works for you and anyone using the API.